# How can I mock the following DBContext call being made using Moq for this C# code?

Tags: c#, moq, dbcontext, xunit.net

I am facing an issue while running the unit test using Moq when the below line is encountered in the service file written in C#. Any valuable inputs on how to mock this particular call will be appreciated here. Thanks. Here _context is instance of DBContext.

var dataObj = _context.FromSqlNotRequired(query, commandParameters).rows;

Unit test setup:

```html
 private readonly Mock<P4IDBContext> _mockContext;
        private readonly Mock<DbSet<MetricsCalibrated>> _metricsCalibratedMockSet;
        private readonly Mock<DbSet<FilterResult>> _filterMockSet;   
        private readonly MetricsService _metricsService;
        private readonly Mock<IMetricsService> metricsService;
        private readonly Mock<Dictionary<String, String>> _dictionary;
        private readonly SourceDataController controller;

        //[Fact()]
        public MetricsServiceTests()
        {
            metricsService = new Mock<IMetricsService>();
           
            controller = new SourceDataController(metricsService.Object);
            _metricsCalibratedMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<MetricsCalibrated>>();
            _metricsCalibratedMockSet.Setup(m => m.AsQueryable()).Returns(_metricsCalibratedData);
            _dictionary = new Mock<Dictionary<String, String>>();
            _filterMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<FilterResult>>();
            _filterMockSet.Setup(m => m.AsQueryable()).Returns(_filterData);
            var commandParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _mockContext = new Mock<P4IDBContext>();
            
            _mockContext.Setup(m => m.MetricsCalibrated).Returns(_metricsCalibratedMockSet.Object);
            _mockContext.Setup(m => m.FilterResult).Returns(_filterMockSet.Object);
            _metricsService = new MetricsService(_mockContext.Object);

        }
```

Error - Message:

```html
Message: 
    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
    RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetFacadeDependencies(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
    RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetDbConnection(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
    DbContextExtensions.FromSqlNotRequired[T](DbContext context, String strSQL, Dictionary`2 commandParameters) line 24
    MetricsService.GetBasicData(String wherePart, IDictionary`2 selectedDict, String timeInterval, Dictionary`2 commandParameters, String tillDate) line 242
    MetricsService.GetFilteredData(FilterOptions options) line 64
    MetricsServiceTests.TestGetFilteredData() line 63
```

Comment: Are you testing the `SourceDataController` or the `metricsService`?

Comment: I am testing the metricsService.

`public void TestGetFilteredData()
        {
            var result = this._metricsService.GetFilteredData(validFilterOptions);
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }`

Comment: Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking)

Comment: FromSqlNotRequired is an extension I am not familar with. Can you share a link to the code/library where this is defined. If it's anything like the built-in FromSql methods, mocking it will probably be quite involved

Comment: @rgvlee 
PFB the code . 

`public static (List<T> rows, List<string> colNames)
                FromSqlNotRequired<T>(this DbContext context, string strSQL, Dictionary<string, string> commandParameters)
                where T : class
        {
            List<T> ret = new List<T>();
            var columns = new List<string>();

            ........
.............................................
            return (ret, columns);
        }`

Comment: You're going to need.to post the entire method

Answer (score 0):

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{ 
    //Below is the setup part. 
    //given  
    var metricsCalibratedData = new List<MetricsCalibrated>
        {
            new MetricsCalibrated{ /* ... */ }, /// fill sample data
            new MetricsCalibrated{ /* ... */ }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockMetricsCalibratedSet = new Mock<DbSet<MetricsCalibrated>>();
        mockMetricsCalibratedSet .As<IQueryable<MetricsCalibrated>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(metricsCalibratedData.Provider);
        mockMetricsCalibratedSet .As<IQueryable<MetricsCalibrated>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(metricsCalibratedData.Expression);
        mockMetricsCalibratedSet .As<IQueryable<MetricsCalibrated>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(metricsCalibratedData.ElementType);
        mockMetricsCalibratedSet .As<IQueryable<MetricsCalibrated>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(metricsCalibratedData.GetEnumerator());

   var filterResultData = new List<FilterResult>
    {
        new FilterResult{ /* ... */ },
        new FilterResult{ /* ... */}
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockFilterResultSet = new Mock<DbSet<FilterResult>>();
    mockFilterResultSet.As<IQueryable<FilterResult>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(filterResultData .Provider);
    mockFilterResultSet.As<IQueryable<FilterResult>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(filterResultData .Expression);
    mockFilterResultSet.As<IQueryable<FilterResult>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(filterResultData .ElementType);
    mockFilterResultSet.As<IQueryable<FilterResult>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(filterResultData .GetEnumerator());

    var mockContext = new Mock<P4IDBContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.MetricsCalibrated).Returns(mockMetricsCalibratedSet.Object);
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.FilterResult).Returns(mockFilterResultSet.Object);

   var sut = new MetricsService(mockContext.Object);
  // Now, the test can b run

  var actualResult = sut.GetFilteredData(validFilterOptions);

  // Then Assert...
```

Comment: I still see the same issue after applying the above code with data.

Comment: Have you declared the `DbSet<MetricsCalibrated>` as virtual in the within the Dbcontext?

Comment: [check this sample code](https://gist.github.com/AJEETX/61a836ba48eb9e2bc3ec67bd88f8c676)

Comment: Yes it is declared as virtual. The main issue here is the following line is not being mocked. The mocked set up should not enter into this method right and return the result. How do we prevent this?

`var dataObj = _context.FromSqlNotRequired(query, commandParameters).rows;`

And it is entering inside this method. 
And inside this method for the following line,  it is giving the exception mentioned above. 
`using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection()`

Comment: Not aware of `FromSqlNotRequired` method, If this is extension method then this can't be mocked.